# avoid * from css styles

Tags: javascript, html, css

i must set styles within other styles from a page that have a style like this:

```
* {
width : 200px;
color : #0000;
}
```

and it applies styles to all tags include my own. 
Is there a way to avoid those styles with asterisks and that my owns are not changed to taht styles?

I've set inline styles in my tags, but the asterisk change it anyways.

Thanks.

Comment: Poor English, I didn't understand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use more [specific](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) selectors to overwrite the existing one. Or you can put your stuff in a `div` with a class and reset CSS for everything inside that `div`.

```
.yourstuff * {
  /* reset your stuff here */
  Width: auto; /* etc. */
}

<div class="yourstuff">
  Your stuff
</div>
```

Comment: ok, that's what i was looking for. The reset of all values that could change any property inside my tag, even if i'vent declared it.

Comment: does not reset all not declared properties :(

Comment: You will have to specify which properties you want to reset of course.

Answer (score 3):

You can set css flag `!important` in your styles to override written styles.

Comment: Unless those styles have the `!important` flag too. Write more specific selectors instead. `!important` is a one use only sledge hammer.

Comment: i've tried to make custom tags, but ie fails to recognize them with xmlns:mytag at the <htm> declaration.

Answer (score 2):

You stated that you couldn't override the * via inline tags but I think what you meant was you couldn't override it via tag attributes. This is correct, CSS will always override the old style tag attributes. If you set them within a style attribute however, it should work fine.

For example:

```
<html>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
* {
    width : 200px;
    color : #000000;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div style="background-color: aqua" width="100%">
    This is some text </div>
<div style="background-color: yellow; width: 100%;">
    This is some text </div>

</body>

</html>
```

The first DIV will be limited to 200px wide because the Width attribute is overridden by your * style.

The second DIV will be 100% of the screen because the Width style will override your * style. CSS works by applying the most specific rule it can find. Because the inline style is as specific as you can get, it always wins.

Comment: nice sample, here is the problem... i don't declare some properties that may have styles declared in a * style, so i must declare all propertires in order that they don't affect my tag. Up is an answer that reset all values to my tag with a specific class. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question. @Jan was spot on.

Answer (score 0):

No.

If a selector matches an element then its rules will apply.

Either:

1. Change the selector so it doesn't match
2. Write new ruleset(s) that override the rules with new ones

Comment: i can't override the actual styles... the key here is that i must set a toolbar at the end of an html that have it's own styles but without changing those styles... I only want that my styles are not overriden with such styles

Comment: Wanting it will not make it possible.